# Почему присваивание работает по-разному?

Tags: c++, указатели, объявление

```
int *p = 25;
```

Вызывает ошибку преобразования int <-> int*, хотя оператор `*` служит именно для значения-по-адресу.

```
int a,b,c,d,*p,x,y,z;
*p=25;
```

Работает прекрасно, значение по указателю 25, а переменная объявлена вместе с другими целочисленными.
Почему именно так?
Пусть так, тогда int и int* разные типы данных и не должны задаваться одной строкой, но это работает в примере с `int a,b,c,d,*p,x,y,z;`, остальные переменные функционируют как должны, не как указатели. А если, например, написать `int* a, b, c;`, то указателем будет только `a`.
И почему не работает следующий код?

```
int *p;
p=&25;
```

Comment: Второй пример записывает 25 по неопределённому адресу (возможно, ноль, но точно не проверял), потому что вы не указали никакой адрес в `*p`. Это неопределённое поведение, на которое компилятор вообще-то очень сильно ругается варнингами. У меня этот пример не работает, а падает с ошибкой сегментирования

Comment: в строке объявления переменных * означает что вы создаете указатель на данный тип. Во всех остальных строках (которые не объявления) * означает взятие значения по адресу. Что касается &25, то это невозможно потому что константы не хранятся в памяти, а непосредственно в коде. А так как константы нет в памяти то и адреса у нее быть не может

Comment: p=&int(25) (здесь я имею ввиду именно не такое присваивание, а что указателью присваивается адрес обьекта),будет работать, поскольку  компилятор знает  сколько памяти выделять.  Инициализация есть выделение памяти, а как обьяснить  &25 копилятору: что это такое? Ведь многие типы могут инициализироваться целым числом..

Comment: Автор, говоря `"не работает"`, уточняйте, либо не компилируется (и приводите сообщение компилятора (а также чем именно компилируете)), либо при запуске на выполнение (OS тоже указывайте), что вы ожидали увидеть, а что *непосредственно наблюдаете.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *p = 25;
```

> Вызывает ошибку преобразования int <-> int*, хотя оператор * служит
>   именно для значения-по-адресу.

В данном предложении не используется оператор разыменования `*`.

Это предложение является объявлением указателя. Сравните к примеру следующее объявление

```
int a[1] = { 25 };
```

Здесь, аналогично, не используется оператор индексирования `[],` а имеет место объявление массива.

То есть одни и те же токены имеют разные значения в зависимости от контекста.

Компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке в этом объявлении

```
int *p = 25;
```

так как нет неявного преобразования целочисленного литерала `25`, имеющего тип `int` к типу значения указателя `int *`.

Что касается этого объявления

```
int a,b,c,d,*p,x,y,z;
```

то его можно переписать как

```
int ( a ), ( b ), ( c ), ( d ), ( *p ), ( x ), ( y ), ( z );
```

которое в данном конкретном случае эквивалентно серии объявлений

```
int ( a );
int ( b ); 
int ( c );
int ( d );
int ( *p );
int ( x );
int ( y );
int ( z );
```

которые, естественно, проще записать как

```
int a;
int b; 
int c;
int d;
int *p;
int x;
int y;
int z;
```

В общем случае простое объявление (в терминах стандарта C++ ***simple-declaration***) упрощенно выглядит следующим образом

```
decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list;
```

То есть последовательность спецификаторов объявлений (int, long, bool и т.д.) и последовательность деклараторов (объявляемых переменных).

Например, в одном предложении-объявлении вы можете объявить, к примеру, объект типа `int`, указатель типа `int *`, массив с элементами типа `int` и функцию (или указатель на функцию), имеющую тип возвращаемого значения `int` или даже `int *`

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную программу

```
#include <iostream>

int f()
{
    return 10;
}

int * g()
{
    static int x = 20;

    return &x;
}

int main() 
{
    int x, *p, a[1], f(), *g(), ( *pf )() = f, *( *pg )() = g;

    p = &x;
    x = 1;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';

    ++*p;

    std::cout << "*p = " << *p << '\n';

    a[0] = x + 1;

    std::cout << "a[0] = " << a[0] << '\n';

    std::cout << "f() = " << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << "*g() = " << *g() << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "pf() = " << pf() << '\n';
    std::cout << "*pg() = " << *pg() << '\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
x = 1
*p = 2
a[0] = 3
f() = 10
*g() = 20
pf() = 10
*pg() = 20
```

Что касается данного фрагмента кода из вашего вопроса

```
int a,b,c,d,*p,x,y,z;
*p=25;
```

то в первом предложении-объявлении объявляется указатель с именем p, который не инициализируется при условии, что эта переменная имеет автоматическую продолжительность памяти (локальная переменная), а потому имеет неопределенное значение, или инициализируется константным null-указателем, если переменная имеет статическую продолжительность памяти (объявлена вне функции).

Второе же предложение является предложением-выражением. В нем используется оператор разыменования указателя `*` и оператор присваивания.

Так как значение указателя либо не определено,либо равно `nullptr`, то это предложение ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Что касается этого предложения

```
int *p;
p=&25;
```

то здесь имеет место попытка взять адрес целочисленного литерала, а не объекта в памяти. Поэтому компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: `int *p;
p=&25;` ... "Поэтому компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке." -- не ошибка, а предупреждение. Работает неправильно, но компилирует и не выдаёт ошибку с преобразованием типов. В другом ответе уже выяснили, что стандарт был придуман такой, что вводит в заблуждение схожестью написания, но разным функционалом. "Здесь, аналогично, не используется оператор индексирования [], а имеет место объявление массива." -- согласен, тут тоже логическая ошибка, "но такой стандарт" (ц)

Comment: @Глеб Оператор & требует lvalue, а целочисленные литералы не являются lvalue.

Comment: действительно, изначально я проверял с помощью `*p=25;`, это вызывало предупреждение, компилировалось, но работало не правильно. `p=&25' не компилируется, перепроверил.

Answer (score 3):

Основная ваша ошибка - это верование в то, что в

```
int *p = 25;
```

присутствует "оператор *" и "присваивание".

На самом же деле никакого "оператора *" и "присваивания" в этом синтаксисе нет. Символ `*` и символ `=` в данном случае являются лишь элементами синтаксиса объявления указателя и синтаксиса инициализации, никакого отношения ни к "оператору *", ни к "присваиванию" не имеющие. Не надо пытаться проводить параллели между символами `*` и `=` в *объявлениях* и операторами `*` и `=` в *выражениях* - это совершенно разные, никак не связанные друг с другом вещи.

В данном объявлении

```
int *p = 25;
```

`p` объявляется как указатель на `int` и делается попытка проинициализировать этот указатель значением `25`. Это не допускается. В языке С++ не существует неявного преобразования значения типа `int` в к типу `int *`.

А вот в этом случае

```
int *p;
*p=25;
```

ваше `*p=25` - это уже не объявление, а *выражение*, в котором у вас уже действительно используется оператор `*` и оператор `=`. Семантический смысл совсем другой.

---

Почему из вашего "`int` и `int*` разные типы данных" (что верно) вы сделали вывод, что они "не должны задаваться одной строкой" - не ясно. Языки С и С++ позволяют вам  объявлять такие переменные одной строкой. Да, верно, в `int* a, b, c;` то указателем будет только `a`. Объявление в С++ состоит из общей части `decl-specifier-seq` и индивидуальных `declarator`

```
decl-specifier-seq declarator, declarator, ...;
```

В вашем примере `int` - это `decl-specifier-seq`, а `* a`, `b` и `c` - это инидивидуальные деклараторы.

---

Ваш вопрос о "почему не работает"

```
int *p;
p=&25;
```

не ясен. Сначала объясните, откуда возник такой вопрос. Почему он вдруг должен "работать"? Указатели в С+ указывают на сущности, расположенные в памяти, т.е. на lvalues. `25` - это литерал, просто некое эфемерное, витающее в воздухе значение. Оно не имеет положения в памяти и к нему невозможно применить оператор взятия адреса `&`.

Comment: Я не спрашивал, `почему не работает?`, мой вопрос, почему со стороны логики запись выглядит ошибочной и вводит в заблуждение. Почему не использован другой способ инициализации указателя сразу в строке объявления? Если существующий вводит в заблуждение, так как запись `*p=&b` при объявлении присваивает в p указатель на b, но не при объявлении эта же запись сделает значение по указателю p равным адресу b.

Comment: @Глеб: Денис Ритчи когда то сказал, что такой синтаксис был выбран для того, чтобы синтаксис *объявления* был похож на синтаксис *использования*. Без сомнения, это была бредовая идея. Синтаксисы-то похожи, но делают они совершенно разные вещи и вызывают вот такие вопросы. Это надо просто запомнить.

Comment: это и есть ответ на вопрос. А кому-то за такой стандарт по рукам надавать надо. Могли бы выбрать совершенно другой способ инициализации при объявлении. 2 года вопрос мучил, на кой лад сделано именно так.

Comment: @AnT, вовсе не бредовая. Она позволяет на ранней стадии распознавать профессионально непригодных

Comment: @Глеб: В "зачаточном" языке С действительно использовался другой синтаксис инициализации: без `=` вообще, т.е. писали просто `int i 42;`. Но уже в K&R было решено все таки добавить туда `=`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *p = 25;
```

Объявлен указатель на `int` с именем `p`. Попытка присвоить указателю целочисленное значение нарушает правила работы с типами С++.

```
int a,b,c,d,*p,x,y,z;
*p=25;
```

Среди переменных типа `int` объявлен указатель на `int` с именем `p`. Выполняется присвоение переменной (месту в памяти) с типом `int`, на которое указывает `p`, переменной типа `int` - без нарушения типов, только вот значение в переменной `p` неизвестно, так что куда именно записывается 25 - неизвестно. Так что поведение программы неопределенное...

```
int* a, b, c
```

`*` относится к имени переменной, а не к типу. Читать надо как

```
int (*a), b, c
```

Здесь

```
int *p;
p=&25;
```

Вы пытаетесь взять адрес от числа, а не переменной. 25 не имеет определенного места в памяти, связанного с ним, и получение его адреса - операция как минимум бессмысленная...

Comment: Вопрос именно в том, почему так? `int a = 20;` -- работает, `int a = 20; int *p = a;` --не работает, `int a = 20; int *p = &a;` -- работает. Но в то же время `int a=20; int *p; *p=&a;` -- будет работать не правильно, а правильно `int a=20; int *p; p=&a;`. В одном случае `*p= &а`, в другом случае `p=&a` будет правильным. Но если брать во внимание такое и начинать обозначать переменные иначе, то строка int* a,b,c; должна была бы создать 3 указателя.

Comment: @Глеб `int *p` — это объявление нового указателя (и неважно, есть = или нету), `int *p = чтототам` это объявление нового указателя с заранее прописанным адресом, `p = чтототам` это запись нового адреса в указатель, `*p = чтототам` это запись по адресу в указателе без изменения самого указателя (не путать с `int *p = чтототам`, это совершенно разные вещи)

Comment: Ну почитайте внимательно учебник, а? Почему так сделан стандарт - это уже не к нам :) Почему так себя ведет ваш код - в соответствии с правилами языка - я пояснил. Правила языка могут казаться вам нелогичными, но компиляторы все равно будут следовать им, а не вашим желаниям, сколь бы обоснованными по сравнению с предложениями этих дураков из комитета по стандартизации они не были...